# Binding list to a HTML textbox is not updating the view

Tags: aurelia

In Aurelia, I have a textbox like this:

```
<input type="text" value.bind="contact.topics|commaList">
```

Where `commaList` is a value converter:

```
export class CommaListValueConverter {
   toView(value) {
     return value.join('|')
   } 

   fromView(value) {
     return value.split('|')
   }
}
```

There are two things:

1. Updating the list (`contact.topics`) from code doesn't change anything in the view. Tried forcing `two-way` as well. The `toView()` is not called (tried to log calls). For comparison, in my view there is also a regular `repeat topic of contact.topics` which update fine.
2. Aurelia modifies my `contact.topics` list by adding an element `__array_observer__: ModifyArrayObserver` to my list. So now I somehow have to clean my list of such unwanted elements before saving (or dirty checking).

I update the array this way:

```
this.contact.topics.push('test')
```

The contents of the array display correctly in the `for of` loop (not shown).

### gist

https://gist.run/?id=dd11c5837b77b29b586d2c4f978a7a48

Comment: It seems that you aren't updating it correctly. Show the code you're using to update the array

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: Can you setup a gist? see it here https://gist.run/?id=7542e061bc940cde506b&sha=6821c521a6c7bae6f59a36fb8628ecd1032b2d10

Comment: Have you tried replacing the array value instead of push?  this.contact.topcis = this.contact.topics.concat('test');

Comment: @efredin it does work to replace the array, don't know why push() doesn't work though, I bet it should

Comment: @specimen, its been my experience that when binding to an array, manipulating the array does not trigger aurelia binding updates.  And while you can create an array observable subscription manually, it doesn't seem like the repeat.for binding makes use of it.  This has always struck me as odd but the bug reports with responses from the aurelia team are confusing at best.

Answer (score 1):

1. Aurelia bindings don't react on Array and Object internal changes unfortunately.
2. You can't escape the `__` private properties that aurelia adds for observation but since you are dirty checking an array you can take a clean clone of it with `arr.slice()`

Comment: Because they explicitly observe the array and its contents and act on them.

You can view the code here https://github.com/aurelia/templating-resources/blob/master/src/repeat.js